# Getting 404 error when dynamic routing in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, next.js13

I am trying to set-up dynamic routing in my NextJS project, using my file: app\pages\content\boots\[...slug].js. I expect to see Slug Path: the-brendan on the page http://localhost:3000/content/boots/the-brendan, based on my code below, but instead I get a 404 error. What could the issue be?

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const BootContent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query; // slug will be an array of each segment

  // Display the slug array as a string for visualization
  // Join the slug array elements with a '/' to reconstruct the path for display
  const slugPath = Array.isArray(slug) ? slug.join('/') : slug;

  console.log(slug); // This will log the slug array to the browser console

  return <div>Slug Path: {slugPath} {/* Displaying the slug path */}</div>;
}

export default BootContent;
```

I'm using Next.js's built-in file-based routing mechanism. Here's a simplified view of my project's folder structure:

```
├── pages
│   ├── _app.js
│   └── content
│       └── boots
│           └── [...slug].js
├── components
│   ├── Header.js
│   └── Footer.js
├── public
│   └── images
└── styles
    ├── globals.css
    └── Home.module.css
```

The `[...slug].js` file is supposed to catch all routes that follow the `/content/boots/` path prefix.

Comment: Please can you add more details to the above question like, *Are you using Page Router or App router ?*, *Please add folder structure of your project.*

Comment: @Beast80K Yep, just added this information to my question. Thanks!